# How do you combine both newtxmath and tgtermes fonts in Luatex

Tags: fonts, luatex, fontspec, typefaces

So I am migrating to LuaTeX after creating my file in PdfTeX and I need help migrating these two fonts into LuaTex

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Tex Gyre Termes}
%% \setmainfont{newtxmath}
```

Comment: Have you checked out section 5, "Usage with LuaLaTeX and XeLaTeX", of the user guide of the `newtxtext` package?

Comment: Yeah but which example should I use? The third one or the fourth one?

Comment: Is using `unicode-math` package with Tex Gyre Termes-Math as the math font, and Tex Gyre Termes as the text font an option? That makes three lines of code.

Comment: @Anon - Which example to use depends strongly on which font options you intend to employ. That's a piece of information you haven't shared so far.